# How to Implement Gmail Drawer Navigation in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

[image]
[image]

I Have used inbuilt android navigation drawer and now i want to implement multi fragment navigation like as gmail.
1.first image When click on Google mail, it will redirect to Google details with back button icon in preview fragment(image2).
2.second image when click on back button its open again first image (main activity with default fragment) instated of navigation drawer.

So Same way i want to implement in my app, Please help me how to achieve this scenario?

In default fragment i have placed editfieds  and submit button. when click on submit button redirect to new fragment, now click on back button on new fragment i want to come back the default fragment.

Comment: instead of using thisgetActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) use addToBackStack(null) ..

Comment: when click on device back i able to go the employee fragment but i want to open a employee fragment when click on drawer button(back icon).

Comment: in AndroidManifest file set android:parentActivityName="" may be this can solve your problem